# How to create dynamic content in Joomla menu

Tags: firebase-realtime-database, joomla3.0

I am completely new to website building with joomla and I was wondering if there is any way to create a menu, where the content would be dynamically filled in from the server. For example, if my website supports different users, and a user clicks on the photos menu, how can i load at that moment the photos that correspond to that selected user?

I am thinking of using firebase as my database since then it would be easier to extend the project to an android app.

Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

The best approach is going to depend on the specifics of your site, to get you started here's one idea and how you would string it together.

Each user creates a Joomla article which has the content you want to appear for them.

You install the [Articles Anywhere](https://extensions.joomla.org/extension/articles-anywhere/) extension.

You create an element which will display the user content, this could be a single Joomla article, or a custom HTML module, and in this element you add the following where you want the user content to appear

```
{articles created_by="user:id"}...{/articles}
```

[More on how this tag works here](https://www.regularlabs.com/extensions/articlesanywhere/tutorial).

That should be it, good luck!